# Can I gate check a laptop with the cabin laptop ban?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, gate-check

Some flights prohibit laptops in the cabin.

Under such circumstances, can one gate check the laptop?  The risk of loss should be lower compared to regular checked luggage, and perhaps the traveller is not (otherwise) checking luggage at all.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What airline are you flying?

Comment: Flights to the USA sometimes have secondary security just before the gate.  What happens if they prohibit you from entering the gate area with your laptop?

Comment: @Johns-305 I'm not actively planning to fly, my aim is to ask a generic question.

Comment: @Tom I don't know.  I have not experienced a luggage search at the secondary security.

Comment: @Tom If the airline has a policy of gate-checking laptops, then there would be need for secondary security to prohibit such.

Comment: @gerrit - I have encountered secondary searches of carry on luggage numerous times before reaching the gate on flights to the USA.

Comment: Create a virtual machine based on a system image of your laptop, (https://www.howtogeek.com/213145/how-to convert-a-physical-windows-or-linux-pc-to-a-virtual-machine), put that VM on an external drive and bring that drive to the US. Then in the US you  run the VM on whatever device you can get hold of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US action affected nine airlines in eight countries across 10 airports. Among those airlines, two immediately announced new gate check services:

- [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/4090646/electronics-ban)
- [Turkish Airlines](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/news-press-release/new-services-on-us-uk-bound-flights).

Several make mention of offering special arrangements, at either check in or gate (or at the US Immigration facility at Abu Dhabi):

- [Qatar Airways](http://support.qatarairways.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004577347-United-States-Travel-Electronic-Devices)
- [Etihad Airways](http://www.etihad.com/en-us/announcements/usa-flights-electronic-device-ban/)

Some refer to the ban, but make no mention of gate check or special arrangements:

- [Royal Jordanian](http://www.rj.com/en/news/title/3842.html)
- [Egypt Air](http://www.egyptair.com/en/about-egyptair/news-and-press/Pages/Banning%20electronic%20devices%20to%20USA.aspx)

The remainder (Saudia, Kuwait Airways, Royal Air Maroc) either have no mention of the ban or it's not easy to locate on its web site.

Carriers affected by the UK government restrictions make mention, but none describe gate check or special services, other than Monarch which notes that such items discovered at the gate will be taken and placed in the hold:

- [British Airways](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/flightops/public/en_us?p_faqid=5709)
- [EasyJet](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/latest-travel-information)
- [Jet2.com](http://www.jet2.com/docs/pdf/turkey-baggage-restrictions.pdf)
- [Monarch](http://blog.monarch.co.uk/uk-security-measures/)
- [Thomas Cook](http://support.thomascook.com/Travel-Advice-Safety/Electronic-Devices-Ban-FAQ-s/)
- [Thomson](http://www.thomson.co.uk/destinations/travel-information/electronics-ban)